# Multiple field entries, best approach

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "Events" , and one of the fields lists "Players", ordered by finishing place, ie (John, Bill, Kyle) is 1st, 2nd and 3rd respectively.

Is this a good format for storing this information? I've been trying to read about normalization but am not sure if I should be looking at a different approach for this.

Furthermore, how would I go about later retrieving this information? I want to be able to go to "Bill"'s profile, and view all the events he placed 1st in.

Thnaks

Comment: By the sound of it you should organise your data in tables called `EVENTS` and `PEOPLE`.  Then link people to events via a table called `ENTRANTS`.  You could then store placing information in the `ENTRANTS` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. Could you expand on this further? I would have a field storing the "Entrants ID" in "Events", and in "Entrants" I could have 1st = "Bill" correct?

Comment: No, you store the event ID and person ID in the `ENTRANTS` table as the primary key, then store additional fields (*eg* `placing`, `did_not_finish`, *etc*).  Please read up on how to form a many-to-many relationship in a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 3 tables:

- USERS (id, name)
- Events (id, name)
- users2events (id_user,id_event,place)

and then searching is simple for Bill's 1'st places -

```
 Select * from 
 users2events where 
 id_user=(select id from users where name='bill') and place=1;
```

Comment: Kind of a dumb question, but in USERS is it important to have an ID? Or can I only have his name there.

Comment: So would it be important to do the same for USERS2EVENTS as well?

Comment: @Wilson "So would it be important to do the same for USERS2EVENTS as well?" - No, because USERS & EVENTS are storing GENERAL_INFO, and users2events stores relation between them

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yaMyrF7.png - Right idea?

Comment: @Wilson, no such thing as a dumb question.  You have to cope with two people having the same name.  An id field is only part of the solution.  You probably need another unique identifier such as a email address.

Comment: Hi, names will be unique so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do I need to use Foreign Keys in this setup? I won't really have a reason to have a unique ID for each entry in USERS2EVENTS, so I assume I wouldn't?

Comment: Also, in each event, I have a field called "LOCATION". If I wanted to retrieve location, or sort first place finishes by location, is it better to store this information in USERS2EVENTS or with EVENTS? Thanks!

Comment: it's good practise... of course if You do have small data You can do that in one table, or wririte in txt file. Location in Events (because it's 'the same' information)